# Creating loop for OneHotEncoding for multiple columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
       ['red', 'apple', 12],
       ['green', 'lemon', 20], 
       ['yellow', 'banana', 18],
])
df.columns = ['color', 'fruit', 'count']
```

I create Labelencoder using apply function

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
cat_columns = df.dtypes[df.dtypes == "object"].index 
df[cat_columns] = df[cat_columns].apply(lambda col: LabelEncoder().fit_transform(col))
```

Then have to create OneHotEncoder for each column separately

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
color = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(df.color.values.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
fruit = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(df.fruit.values.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()

dfOneHot = pd.DataFrame(color, columns = ["Color_"+str(int(i)) for i in range(color.shape[1])])
df = pd.concat([df, dfOneHot], axis=1)

dfOneHot = pd.DataFrame(fruit, columns = ["Fruit_"+str(int(i)) for i in range(fruit.shape[1])])
df = pd.concat([df, dfOneHot], axis=1)
```

Two Questions?

1. Is it possible to do OneHotEncoder in loop instead of one by one column?
2. Instead of giving _1,_2,_3 using i values, is it possible to give Color_apple, Color_lemon and Color_banana and Fruit_apple, Fruit_lemon, Fruit_banana so that naming make sense ?

Comment: are you looking for `df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.select_dtypes('O')))` ??

Comment: No, not with get_dummies, only with OneHotEncoder

Comment: some thing like

for colname in list(cat_columns):
    X = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(df.colname.values.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
    OneHot = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = ["{}_"+str(int(i)) for i in range(X.shape[1])])
    df = pd.concat([df,OneHot], axis=1)